# How to replace NetAPP storage with Azure Storage in SQL Server 2019?

Tags: sql-server-2019, failover-cluster-instance

I have 2 node failover cluster in SQL Server 2019 Standard Edition. All the storage is in NetAPP. Now we want to get rid of NetAPP storage and would like to replace it with Azure Storage. How we can do it without changing the Instance name with zero down time. We have around 81 databases in the instance

Any other recommendations?